# how to get the memory mapping for a core on Linux/HPUX (pmap)

Tags: linux, solaris, hp-ux, memory-mapping, pmap

On solaris i can run the pmap command on a core file to get the memory map of a crashed process. Unfortunately the pmap command available on HPUX and Linux doesn't provide this option. Any pointers how i can get this information on these platforms?

Comment: I'm not familiar with pmap/Solaris.  What information are you looking for that the pmap command provides?

Comment: Well i want to know placement and size of the stack, the heap, text segments, shared library mappings, mmaped areas, thread stacks, shared memory, etc... Basically the whole memory layout. All this information is available from pmap but only for running-processes (unless on solaris where its also available for cores).

Answer (score 0):

`objdump -p core`

That will give the information from the first three columns of `pmap`, but in a different format.  The first three columns in `pmap` correspond to the `vaddr`, `memsz` and `flags` values in the `objdump` output resepectively.

The fourth column from `pmap`, the path of the mapped file, appears to be unavailable from the `core` file.